# Java file not found even though file exists

Tags: java, file, path

Have a method that takes in a file path and then checks the contents of that file.
File structure of the project is:

```
    filePathTesting
     ┣test
     ┃ ┣ TestCard.java
     ┃ ┣ TestCardGame.java
     ┃ ┗ valid5PlayersPack.txt
     ┗src
       ┣ App.java
       ┣ Card.java
       ┗ CardGame.java
```

method within src/CardGame.java

```
public static boolean isValidPackFile(String packLocation, int numPlayers)
    {
        File file = new File(packLocation);
        if (file.exists() && file.isFile()){
            try (BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(packLocation))){
                String line;
                int lineCount = 0;
                while((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
                    try {
                        int num = Integer.parseInt(line);
                        if (num<=0){
                            System.out.println("ERROR: Pack file contains a non-positive integer");
                            return false;
                        }
                        lineCount++;
                    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                        System.out.println("ERROR: Pack file contains a non-integer");
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                if(lineCount==numPlayers*8){
                    return true;
                }else{
                    System.out.println("ERROR: There are not " + 8*numPlayers + " cards in the pack file");
                    return false;
                }
            }catch(IOException e){
                System.out.println("ERROR: Could not read pack file");
                return false;
            }
        }
        else { 
            System.out.println("ERROR: Pack file does not exist");
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Test method within test/TestCardGame.java

```
@Test
    public void testIsValidPackFileValidFile() throws IOException{
        int numPlayers=5;
        String filePath="valid5PlayersPack.txt";
        System.out.println(new File(".").getAbsolutePath());
        assertTrue("Valid file not recognised as valid", CardGame.isValidPackFile(filePath, numPlayers));
    }
```

When running CardGame.java, passing in "test/valid5PlayersPack.txt" as the file path works as expected and no errors are encountered.

When using JUnit to test the method and passing in the exact same file path, no file is found.
Have also tried passing in:

```
valid5PlayersPack.txt  
../test/valid5PlayersPack.txt  
../valid5PlayersPack.txt  
src/test/valid5PlayersPack.txt  
../test/valid5PlayersPack.txt
```

yet each time it says no file was found

I've tried passing in the file path relative to the TestCardGame and CardGame but can never get a valid file path.

I also used:

```
System.out.println(new File(".").getAbsolutePath());
```

and the last bit of the path is the "filePathTesting_dba1f5ce/." which all seems correct

Any help would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: ’and the last bit of the path is the "filePathTesting_dba1f5ce/." which all seems correct’. Where does the ‘dba1f5ce’ part come from? How are the tests run? Does it copy the compiled classes to another directory, and perhaps skips the text file?

Comment: @TimMoore now that i properly look at the absolute path "Application Support/Code/User/workspaceStorage/a18f9fb460a8e5c9aaa19c99e70743cd/redhat.java/jdt_ws/filePathTesting_dba1f5ce/." its going through what I think is the VS code cache and not the actual directory of the project in my folders which could potentially be whats causing the issue

Comment: Managed to find that folder and the only contents of it are an empty bin folder which I'm guessing is the issues, but I can't find how to change the path to go through where the actual project is saved in my documents as opposed to this way

Comment: Sorry, I haven’t used VS Code with Java, but now that you have tracked down that issue it would be a good idea to rewrite the question with a focused title and appropriate tags. Something like “How can I configure the working directory when running JUnit tests in VS Code?”

Comment: Please - no images of text. They are not searchable, we cannot copy-paste. Always copy-paste the text and format it properly.
The command `tree filePathTesting` followed by a copy and paste *as source code* here will help you and us much more. You will get on better if you load your pack file as a resource, so `try (BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream(packLocation)))){` passing in a correct resource path (which is *not* a file path). Unfortunately I can't give you that path as I'm still not clear what your project/package structure is

Comment: @TimMoore you are a life saver, turns out JUnit was using a different working directory for the tests than the working directory for actually running the classes. Thank you so much

Comment: You wouldn't need to do that if you used the classpath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that JUnit was using a different working directory to the directory actually used by the classes when they're run. Massive thanks to @TimMoore for the help.
The solution was changing the working directory for java.test.config in settings.json